# Duplicate error when transferring Magento to 127.0.0.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, mysql-error-1064, duplicates

One of my clients have a rairly big website. For some reason I had to transfer the website to the localhost.

The database is over 1GB but I still managed to import it via phpmyadmin.

Now when I go to the front end I get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '2386019' for key 'PRIMARY'

I've googled around but non of the solution seem to be solving the problem.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Dom

Comment: Can you dump the client's database with mysqldump and import it with mysql? I wouldn't trust such a big import via phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that despite the fact that it appeared the database was imported some parts timed out.

Here is a link which explains how to import via the dos command line, this works much better for large database imports: http://www.technotaste.com/blog/easy-mysql-import-from-the-command-line-on-windows/